# Debootstrap for Backbox Error with release file

Tags: chroot, debootstrap

I'm trying to install a BackBox (Ubuntu based) chroot environment with debootstrap using the following command:

```
sudo debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch i386 trusty /MYJAIL/ http://ppa.launchpad.net/backbox/four/ubuntu
```

and I get the following error:

```
E: Failed getting release file http://ppa.launchpad.net/backbox/four/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

I verified that the file exists in that url and I can connect without any problems to the server.

What else I can do to try to do it work?

Thanks for any help.